# Can you use ASP.NET MVC Futures library and MVC source code side by side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to using the Html.RenderAction<> method from the ASP.NET MVC Futures library.  However, I can only make this work if my project references the System.Web.Mvc assembly in the GAC.  If I include the System.Web.Mvc source code as a project in my solution, then everything with Microsoft.Web.Mvc blows up.  Anyone else have this experience?  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To use MVC source code, there are two web.config files to edit :
- /web.config
- /views/web.config

You have to remove the PublicKey attribute from those lines (by memory, the example below may not be 100% accurate, but you get the idea :)):

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=x.y.z.a, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789101112"/>
```

or

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=x.y.z.a, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0123456789101112"/>
```

so it becomes

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=x.y.z.a, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

or

```
<add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=x.y.z.a, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

Comment: It's a total pain in the rear.  I wish the MS team would do a better job at making these early releases integrate smoother.

Comment: This only worked for me if I dont use ASP.NET MVC Futures. If I use ASP.NET MVC Futures I get: CS0012: The Type "System.Web.Mvc.Controller" is contained in a unreferenced assembly.